# WebElement Click() showing NullPointerException in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver, junit4

I was trying Selenium automation testing in https://www.yatra.com/etw-desktop/ . My objective was to click an Image Button named 'Asia' which will redirect to another page (Images attached). I copied the full XPath and tried but I am getting a NullPointerException. Please give some suggestions since I didn't find anything wrong with my code.

```
package com.stackroute.SeleniumProject;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

/**
 * JUnit project.
 */
public class Yatra {
    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    @FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/my-app//app-drawer-layout/app-header-layout/iron-pages/my-home//div/div/div/div/paper-material[2]/div[1]/div/a[2]/div[4]")
    WebElement Asia;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        String chromePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib/chromedriver.exe";// directory of chrome driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void close() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.yatra.com/etw-desktop/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // the error is in the below line Asia.click()

        Asia.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Assert.assertEquals("page not found", "https://www.yatra.com/etw-desktop/city-list", driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }

}
```

[Image showing the element to be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRIIu.png)

[Image of web page after click operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lWcs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using PageFactory(from page object model), so you will need to init() the webelements.

For this you will need to import

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
```

An before starting the test, you will need to initialise the elements:

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)  // where you pass the driver and this class to know which webelements to start.
```

You can take a look here to understand the approach and another POM framework easier to understand [TUTORIAL](https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html)

Comment: ,I didnt meant to use PageFactory. So I removed @FindBy and added `driver.findElement(By.xpath(.....)).click();` in the test instead of `Asia.click();` and I am getting No Such Element Exception. Is there any limitation for click() when div is involved in html XPath?

Comment: is your webelement inside of an iframe?

Comment: No.I checked the console. I tried impicit and expicit waits. Still not clicking on the 'Asia' image button(shown in the attached image of my question).`new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable   (By.xpath("//*[@id=\"scrollable1\"]/div[1]/div/a[2]/div[4]"))).click();`

Comment: one question, if you look after that locator in browser's console, are you able to locate it and see it highlighted?

Comment: Its highlighted. The divs are under a #shadow-root(open).I don't know if that's the problem since I am seeing this for the first time.